# using inheritance and calling in other class

Tags: python, oop

code:

```
class aa:
    def getDis():
        return 0

class bb(aa):
    def getDis():
        return 10

class cc(aa):
    def getDis():
        return 15

class d:
    def __init__(self,cust):
        self.cust = cust
        self.memberLevel = aa()

    def cgl(self,amt):
        if amt ==1:
            self.memberLevel = bb()
        elif amt ==2:
            self.memberLevel = cc()
        else:
            self.memberLevel = aa()
```

Well i have these four classes. What i am trying to do is that in my top three classes i have inheritance. In my class d i am trying to call the respective method if the amount is 1 0r 2 . Instead it is giving me this output:

```
 d1 = d('one')
 d1.cgl(1)
 print(d1.memberLevel)
```

output:

```
 <__main__.bb object at 0x036D7BF0>
```

So help required that how can i use overriding technique.

Comment: What were you expecting instead? How is inheritance relevant here?

Comment: Everything seems to be working as you intended? It's unclear what kind of output you were expecting from `print(d1.memberLevel)` as you are not actually calling any methods, you are only creating instances inside `cgl`

Comment: well its inhertance in top three classes and i am trying to do method overridding. if you see in my class i am calling respective method of class if the amount is 1 or 2. i need to get the answer 10 from the function of class bb.

Comment: *"i am calling respective method of class"* - no you aren't, you're creating an instance of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you were hoping to see the console output:`10`

Because d1.memberLevel is the bb class itself (not the value 10, and not the function that returns the value 10), the console output shows `<__main__.bb object at 0x036D7BF0>`.  This is correct behavior when `print`ing an object directly.

Perhaps your last line of console code should say:

```
print(d1.memberLevel.getDis())
```

Another option would be to assign the value within the "d" class:

```
self.memberLevel = bb().getDis()
```

And the member methods require "self", e.g.:

```
def getDis(self):
    return 10
```

Comment: getDis is not method of class d. Instead it is the overriding method in class aa, bb , cc. so on correct result it should call respective class method.

Comment: @Kam yes, but the `memberLevel` *is* an instance of `aa` or its descendants.

Comment: memberLevel is instance attribute of class d. i have initalized it with aa().

Comment: if amt ==1:
   self.memberLevel=bb()
   self.memberLevel.getDis()                i have done this too but it gives error that :                                                                                 self.memberLevel.getDis()
TypeError: getDis() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @Kam yes, and do you understand why this error occurs? (hint: it has nothing to do with `class d` or its methods)

Comment: Thanks. Can u explain why the error occurred. I am a bit confused

Comment: @Kam in all seriousness, it's not practical to coach you through this step by step on SO; this isn't a tutorial service. I'd strongly recommend you go and read through a decent tutorial (see e.g. http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F).

Comment: @anroegan ... ur answer works but secong option doesnt. bcz ur directly calling a method of class without creating its instance. so it gives me error

Comment: @Kam You're right, I had a typo there.  Take a look at the update.  This should work as well.

Comment: @Kam In this scenario, you're not getting any benefit from the inheritance.  This is because the new classes just redefine the only function.  Here's an  example where the new class gets to use the inherited methods for free.   http://www.python-course.eu/inheritance_example.php